# Azure Active Directory BitLocker Key doesn't appear

Tags: azure-active-directory, bitlocker

My laptop started to got blue screen and now I cannot make it run without the BitLocker recovery key. Looks like this key was assigned when registered the laptop to AAD but I can't find it here (I can see the BitLocker of other colleagues). Basically I need to know is there is way to get back this key from somewhere to avoid to lost all my laptop data, any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried checking your  Microsoft account? Reference : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4530477/windows-10-finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key

Comment: Yep, I tried that, my account doesn't exist there :(

Comment: The best approach would be to open a support case for the same but they might also be unable to help if the key was not copied to AAD/Intune.